# change the font size of \part (depth -1) to LARGE or Large in tocstyle

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, formatting, parts, tocstyle

I am using `tocstyle` package to format my TOC. It works nicely. 
However, I just want to increase a little bit the title of the `\part` in the TOC. It seems that `tocstyle` uses `\large` font as default for the `\part`. Is there anyway to increase the size of `\part` title to `\Large` or `\LARGE` in `tocstyle`?

I can of course have a larger font for `\part` without using `tocstyle`. But my question really is to achieve the larger font for `\part` and use `tocstyle` at the same time since it provides me a nice format of TOC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\settocstylefeature[-1]{entryhook}{\LARGE\bfseries}
```

(change `\LARGE` according to your needs). A complete example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}

\settocstylefeature[-1]{entryhook}{\LARGE\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{Test part}
\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is that possible to assign an arbitrary size like 12.5pt or so? I have tried \settocstylefeature[-1]{entryhook}{\12pt\bfseries} and \settocstylefeature[-1]{entryhook}{12pt\bfseries} and \settocstylefeature[-1]{entryhook}{{12pt}\bfseries}. Nothing works so far.